# Binding within DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, binding, lazy-loading, selecteditem

I've got *academic lectrurers* collection which is fetched from the database using **Entity Framework**.

`Lecturers` is a property within `LecturerListViewModel`:

```
public ObservableCollection<Lecturer> Lecturers { get; set; }
```

`Lecturer` is class from database reverse engineering:

```cs
public class Lecturer
{
    public Lecturer()
    {
    }

    public int Id_Lecturer { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? Academic_Degree_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual AcademicDegree AcademicDegree { get; set; } // lazy loading
}
```

I want to display all the lecturers from database in `DataGrid` (all cells of the grid are editable; when user click **Save** button all the data will be saved in DB). 
The problem is binding recent academic degree to combobox. I tried this way:

```xml
<StackPanel d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=ViewModel:LecturerListViewModel}">
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Lecturers}" HeadersVisibility="Column">
        <DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Academic degree">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <!-- PROBLEM HERE. SelectedItem="{Binding AcademicDegree}" doesn't work -->
                        <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding AcademicDegree}" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.AcademicDegrees}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="100"  Margin="15" Name="AddLecturerButton" />
</StackPanel>
```

`ItemsSource="{Binding Lecturers}"` is binded correctly. There is list after click on the `checkbox`. But after program startup the values in `checkboxes` are empty. Why? How can I fix it?

PS. `LecturerListViewModel` is binded in code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

Your objects need to provide change notifications via [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx). (So if the lazy loading is done a notification needs to be made for the property)

Comment: Hey! Binding to `Name` works even without implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Just `ComboBox` doesn't work properly. I've changed my `Lecturer` class to [this version](http://wklej.org/id/867503/) but still there is no selected value in `ComboBoxes`. What's wrong?

Comment: @patryk.beza: There are too many things that *could* be wrong, notifications are just among the most common causes...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind Enum values to a combobox you have to provide an IEnumerable with the enum values. The easiest way to achive this is by defining an `ObjectDataProvider` in your Resources.

```
 xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
 xmlns:MyEnums="clr-namespace:LocalNamespaceWhereAcademicDegreeIsDefined"    
 ...
 <Window.Resources>
     <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="AcademicDegrees" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}" >
         <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
             <x:Type TypeName="MyEnums:AcademicDegree"/>
          </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
     </ObjectDataProvider>
 <Window.Resources>
 ...
 ...
 <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding AcademicDegree}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource AcademicDegrees}}" />
 ...
 ...
```